# Using Postman Collections as a source in a Ruby on Rails code generation pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman, openapi

The problem I'm experiencing is that I have some alternatives and theoretical ideas in mind, though I don't really know which one is best to choose.

**Problem description**
I got a big enough Postman API collection of 20-30 supplier APIs. It's been built based on various OpenAPI imports from each supplier's public specification and for some it was a manual collection writing based on their .DOC or .PDF docs.
It's been accumulating for 2 years now, our Postman collection.

I started to work on an internal project, a Ruby on Rails API that needs to communicate to these 20-30 suppliers, and in order to integrate to them, I have to manually write the API Adapter layer mapping the tests and examples from Postman. I use the [RestClient Ruby gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/2.1.0/RestClient).

In order to save time with the process, I've been thinking of a way to improve this development experience and eventually save some time.

**The options I could think of**
I have in mind:

1. Either to manually export the Postman Library as OpenAPI JSON, supplier by supplier, collection by collection, and use each of the 20-30 resulting JSON files as input for [OpenAPI Code Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

   1. Regarding the manually export part, maybe there's a way to make it automatic by using Postman Collection Runner or maybe via Newman CLI
   2. Regarding the JSON files, I believe the codegenerator works with YAML and maybe I need a JSON -> YAML convertor in between
   3. In order to keep Postman in sync with Rails RestClient adapter layer, I thought that maybe there's some sort of pipeline I could build, so when a change occurs in the collection to trigger a job to get the code for it
2. To make use of Postman as a sort of microservice, making it the place to go, develop, configure the supplier APIs library and then to connect the Rails service with a sort of Rails gem Postman REST client adapter, and hopefully to have some autocomplete.
3. To export and migrate whole Postman collections to a sort of API aggregator tool. Any recommendation might help. Then to connect with Rails to that tool.

Hope it makes some sense and hope I'm not asking too much details. If you knew of any such projects or references, that might help.

Comment: An app that has to communicate with 20-30 different APIs is a huge project - especially in terms of maintainence.

Comment: @max, indeed, that's why I believe there might be a better way to develop it, reducing maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone further interested about this question, I moved away from the idea of using "Postman as a microservice", and moved to the idea of UI drag and drop API connection builders, such as commercial solutions: Azure Data Factory, Talend (either Data Integration product or Data Manangement), as well as Open Source solutions Talend Open Studio, Apache Nifi.

I hope there'll be an easy way to import the OpenAPI schema specs from Postman to either of these tools, to make the API configuration as neat and as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the makeup of the 20-30 schemas, I'd suggest option 4: Use [openapi-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge) with [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/)

I'm assuming that these 20-30 APIs are all 3rd party, meaning you have no control over them.  That's fine.  Export them all from postman to their individual json files.  Add them to `openapi-merge` to create one gigantically massive openapi specification.  Use the new specification with the `openapi-generator` to generate your code.

Benefits:

1. `openapi-merge` uses the first input specification as the default in the event of conflicts.  This allows you to define a separate file with your own custom info, server, tags, etc in it.
2. `openapi-generator` enforces an [API first](https://www.postman.com/api-first/) approach to coding.  This ensures that your code always matches the schemas of your 3rd-party APIs.
3. The `openapi-generator` will take your json and convert it to yaml for you.  No string attached.
4. As I'm sure you're already aware, the `openapi-generator` is extremely customizable.  You can customize the produced files via the mustache templates, or customize the generator itself with your own generator.  It supports multiple languages, and configurations and can generate a working server out of the box.

Drawbacks:

1. Because `openapi-merge` resolves conflicts by taking the FIFO approach, if any of the schemas have conflicting object names or parameters, they will get overwritten.

Comment: Hi @tbatch. that makes sense, thanks. Indeed it's third parties. They provide us with the docs, most of the times in OpenAPI, but sometimes in PDF or .DOC files :) 
It's a complex solution, both steps I mentioned and the option 4. Should be doable and I suppose it will be pretty stable. From what I see `openapi-merge` got some traction as a project, seems stable.
I've got not much experience with the generator project, not sure what I can and can't configure. I only got it running last year to generate the codebase and a gem for one of these 20 suppliers. By default it did an amazing job

Comment: I'll admit there's a bit of a learning curve to the generator.  If it's your first time using it, start small.  Make a small openapi spec (the petstore works good for this) and generate stuff to see what happens.  Make a change, and generate again.  You can use some of the examples on the [generators github](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples) to get a general idea, but I've found [the tests](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/java/org/openapitools/codegen) are much better to learn from.